# Python TypeError - 'Class' object is not callable (Google Collab Example Inside)

Tags: python, pytorch, typeerror, pytorch-lightning

[Redacted]

In this example, in my final cell of code, I try to call my model.  This is following the tutorial on a Youtube video.

In this step, the video is able to perform the lines

`model = UCC_Classifier(config)`

then in the next cell

`loss, output = model(input_ids.unsqueeze(dim=0), am.unsqueeze(dim=0), labels.unsqueeze(dim=0))`

To successfully get a result.  However when I try and do the same thing, I get told my class is not callable.  I cannot see any difference and am unsure why this might not be callable.

Thanks

Comment: Please include relevant code here, not links to code.

Comment: @erip Can do in future. Just curious - any reason why? It seems like allowing people to run a notebook direct and see the exact same thing is better/easier than copy-pasting, but if I can't in future I won't.

Comment: Links can be cleaned up or otherwise disappear. Self-contained code in these questions will not.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question about this collab notebook in general then?  The first two lines I have are `!pip install transformers` and `!pip install pytorch-lightning` and sometimes when I reload the notebook (like now), it becomes unusable.  I get the error when I try to import pytorch_lightning that `ValueError: transformers.models.auto.__spec__ is None`.  However othertimes when I reload, I dont get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UCC_Classifier` model should be a `pl.LightningModule`, not a `pl.LightningDataModule`.